# Can one use SignalR without hubs and without broadcast?

Tags: signalr

I would like to use SignalR for its support of asynchronous server-to-client and the elegant fallback in cases where the browser have no web sockets.

My application, however, is strictly unicast - the client makes a connection, subscribes to some data which are sent to the client when the come into existence.  No broadcast is relevant.  And the application does not match the "Hubs" architecture at all.

And here is my problem:  I have searched for several days for documentation, or just an example on how to send data to just one client.  Similar questions have been asked earlier, also on stackoverflow, but I have found none with a useful answer.

So: I sit in (a closure created in) OnReceived, I have some data (String s), and I wish to send 's' to just the client that caused the OnReceived callback to happen.  It is *really* very very simple.  But all I can find is Connection.Send, and that calls for a ConnectionMessage, which in its turn calls for a Signal.  Which I do not know what is nor how to create and subscribe to.

I am starting to think that SignalR may be simply the wrong tool (in the sense that its design is too broadcast-focused for my needs).  On the other hand, no simpler tool seems to offer the same elegant solution for the bidirectional communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's strange because there's a section on this page https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection with the title Sending to a specific connection. Where did you look for docs?

Comment: Yes, I did look in the wiki page; after all, that is a natural place to look.  Somehow I succeeded in overlooking that paragraph :-(.  And then I studied the source codes and found nothing in the IConnection class - because that version of Send is an extension method, they can be a little hard to find.  Thank you for your answer, it solves my problem entirely.  Now I can get on with my project.

Comment: Can we also use this PersistentConnection to stream the data?